The Dart Analyzer has terminated. after flutter upgrade
The Dart Analyzer has terminated.  showing continually after fluter upgrade
flutter upgrade
after this the issue happened, also not able to work because of it not showing any error ,
Errors showing

The Dart Analyzer has terminated.
Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
The Dart Analysis Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
